# Larvel displaying checkmarked values on other page

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel. Currently, I am trying to use Laravel to display check marked values on other pages. In vanilla PHP, I can easily do this with $_SESSION[]. Is there any good documentation on how to use $_SESSIONs in Laravel?

Just to clarify, I am NOT interested in submitting check marked values to the database; rather take the check marked values and display the values on different pages.

Answer (score 0):

Working with `sessions` in Laravel is pretty straightforward and you can find everything in Laravel documentation.

Specifically for working with `sessions`, you can find everything at this link: https://laravel.com/docs/session

Comment: At best this is a comment to a question that didnt need asking as all the information is available to those that can read in the Laravel documentaion

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by

> check marked values

But the `$_SESSION[]` variable is available when using Laravel too, since you are just using a framework on top of "vanilla php".